# How to obtain the sum of an infinite series? is it divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}e^{(i-\tfrac{1}{n})/20}$$

The problem is from a continuous compound interest related calculation (but I made a mistake in deduction, the $\frac{1}{n}$ here should be $\frac{n}{m}$, then the series is expected to be convergent and the guessed value is expected to be $$20(e-1).$$

Though the deduction is wrong, how to obtain the sum of the `wrong` infinite series seems still interesting.

**Update**

The following conversion solves my original problem if $\frac{1}{n}$ is $\frac{n}{m}$:

$$\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}e^{(i-\tfrac{n}{m})/20}$$
$$=\int_{0}^1 {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}e^{(i-t)/20}}dt$$

So it is quite simple...

thanks to @Did

Comment: I soon obtained an answer by converting the limit into integral, and it is $20(e-1)$

Comment: It is acceptable -and even encouraged- to answer your own question, and to accept your own answer, thus freeing the *Unanswered Questions* queue.

Comment: For your interest the value of the limit when $m\to\infty$ is not $20(e-1)$ but $$\frac{e-1}{1-e^{-1/20}}.$$ And I do not understand the "conversion" presented in the "update".

Comment: You can check your results via Wolframalpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BIntegrate%5BE%5E%28%28k+-+t%29%2F20%29%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+20%7D%5D+%2F%2F+Simplify&dataset=

Comment: @Did the conversion is based on the definition of integral as a limit of summation; or you can post your answer in detail below.

Comment: "the conversion is based on the definition of integral as a limit of summation" I would be curious to see the details of such a conversion... (But it is rather odd to send people back to the WA evaluation of the integral when they say the integral is unrelated to the problem.)

Comment: thank you! It seems I need to reconsider it thoroughly. there should be something wrong

Comment: The original limit should be $$\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{20}e^{(i-\tfrac{n}{m})/20}$$

Comment: But how do you obtain the $$\frac{e-1}{1-e^{-1/20}}$$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{20}\exp\left(\frac{i-\frac{1}{n}}{20}\right)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{20n}\right)\color{purple}{\sum_{i=1}^{20}\exp\left(\frac{i}{20}\right)}$$
but the last sum is just a constant, so let we evaluate the interesting part:

$$ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{20n}\right)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k! 20^k n^k}=1-\frac{H_m}{20 m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right).$$
That gives that the wanted limit is just the purple constant.